# Create user using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

How can I create a user in linux using a bash script already knowing the username and password.

Lets say the username will be variable `$username` and password will be `$password`.

I also dont want it to print anything. I simply want to run a .sh file and have it create the user with a static variable I defined.

I am having issues trying to accomplish this. Also I assume I need to encrypt the text version of my password in sha-512

I tried this below no luck

```
sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash -p $password $username
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about that isn't working exactly? Have you tried not setting the password with `useradd` and setting it with `passwd` after that?

Comment: I dont want to have userinput to set the pass. I want it set by the bash script as i chosen.

Comment: `passwd` can take passwords via standard input.

Comment: But is there a way to do it without user input at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "$password" | sudo passwd --stdin "$username"
```

Comment: `passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'`

Answer (score 3):

You haven't told us what exactly is going wrong but `useradd` requires a crypted (or otherwise possibly) password. It might be better to just let `passwd` do the work for you.

```
sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash "$username"
echo "$password" | sudo passwd --stdin "$username"
```

Comment: I want to be able to set the password i have in the bash file. Is that possible without user input?

Comment: This shouldn't require any user input as far as I know.

Comment: Let me test it hold on

Comment: It says `unrecognized option --stdin`

Comment: Might not be available in your version of `passwd` then. What OS/etc. is this? Without that I think you are left with manually `crypt`ing/etc. the password and using the original attempt (which you still haven't indicated the problem with).

Comment: Sure, can you show me in the right direction how to do so?

Im using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Looks like ubuntu has a `chpasswd` command you might be able to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

as root:

```
adduser $username && echo "$username:$password" | chpasswd
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "username: " username
useradd -m -s /bin/bash $username
passwd $username
```

try this v2.

Comment: But is there a way to make it add the password without user input?